# "Select forward layer" keyboard shortcut - include invisible layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Due to my non-US keyboard I've had to make an Action that maps "Select forward layer" to an F-key.

However the "Select forward layer" doesn't select invisible layers.

Is there a way to select the forward layer, despite it being invisible?

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten the provided code using recursion.  It is much cleaner and handles unlimited nested groups.

It also has better (and configfurable) handling of hidden groups and their contents, which was an issue in the original code.

```
// Setting the activeLayer in photoshop automatically makes it visible, so to
// traverse through the layer stack without ruining it we need to check if a
// layer is hidden first, then restore its state after activation.

// Unfortunately any layer within a hidden group appears hidden regardless of
// its true state in the interface.  As we cannot know its true state we must
// are forced to set any layer within a hidden group to either visible or
// hidden.  Your preferred behavior can be chosen in activateLayer().

// Alternatively, we can simply skip over the contents of hidden layer groups.
// I recommend this behavior as navigating within a a hidden group has limited
// usefulness.

var skipHiddenGroups = true;

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;
var activateNext = false;

function traverseLayers(layers, inHiddenGroup) {
    if (inHiddenGroup && skipHiddenGroups)
        return;

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        var layer = layers[i];

        if (activateNext) {
            activateLayer(layer, inHiddenGroup);
            activateNext = false;
        } else if (layer === currentLayer) {
            activateNext = true;
        }

        if (layer.typename === "LayerSet") {
            traverseLayers(layer.layers, (!layer.visible || inHiddenGroup));
        }
    }
}

function traverseLayersReverse(layers, inHiddenGroup) {
    if (inHiddenGroup && skipHiddenGroups)
        return;

    for (var i = layers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var layer = layers[i];
        if (layer.typename === "LayerSet") {
            traverseLayersReverse(layer.layers, (!layer.visible || inHiddenGroup));
        }

        if (activateNext) {
            activateLayer(layer, inHiddenGroup);
            activateNext = false;
        } else if (layer === currentLayer) {
            activateNext = true;
        }
    }
}

function activateLayer(layer, inHiddenGroup) {
    var isVisible = layer.visible
    doc.activeLayer = layer

    if (inHiddenGroup) {
        // Ignore layers that are within a hidden group as we cannot know their true state.
    } else if (!isVisible) {
        doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
    }
}

// Call traverseLayers or traverseLayersReverse depending on which direction you want to go.
traverseLayers(doc.layers, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by forward layer you mean top layer, you can do this with a simple script. Open your ExtendScript Toolkit (it should have installed along with Photoshop) and make a new Javascript document. Then enter:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument; //references current document
doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[0]; //selects the top layer
```

This will make the top layer visible when it's selected. If you want to keep it invisible, add the following line at the end:

```
doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
```

Save it in your Presets/Scripts folder for convenience (though it can go anywhere).

Then go into Photoshop, make a new file, start recording a new Action, then go to File > Scripts > Browse, and find your script. Opening it runs it. Once it's run, stop recording and just assign a shortcut key to the action, *et voila*!

If for any reason you can't find the ExtendScript Toolkit, just put the code in a blank text document and change the extension to .jsx . If you move the script file after you've recorded the action you will have to re-record it as it remembers the path.

Comment: By "forward" I mean "next" layer - is there a way to script selecting the "next" or "previous" layer? Photoshop's built in action allows you to select next and previous layers, however it ignores invisible layers. I don't want to change the visibility of the layer, I just want to be able to select them regardless of visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by slightly modifying the script I found on AHK forum (that one switched target layer forcefully to visible and had other minor errors), and it's works for me:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;


for(i=0; i < doc.layers.length; )
{         
  if(doc.layers[i]==currentLayer)
  {
      a=i;
      //alert(a);
      i = doc.layers.length;
  }
  else{ i++; }
}


try
{
  var nextLayer = doc.layers[a+1];
  var check = nextLayer.visible;
}
catch(e)
{
  var nextLayer = doc.layers[0];
  var check = nextLayer.visible;
}  

doc.activeLayer = nextLayer;
if (check == false)
  doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
```

This is for stepping to the next (down) layer; for previous (up) just make another script with changes [a+1] to [a-1] in TRY section and [0] to [doc.layers.length-1] in CATCH section.
Well, in the following, the common way: place both scripts in Ps script folder, make Action with "Insert Menu Item" and assign hotkeys as you wish. You may later use even your fav AHK shortcuts and so on...

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to the scripts above.

After testing those in Ps I've stumbled upon the fact that if there are groups in the current workflow, scripts don't work properly. They don't take in account layers inside groups, known as layerSets in script language; when the script lists through "layers" it handles only upper level elements (layers outside groups and groups themselves).

So I took a try to adjust them to more extended needs.

Modified scripts are below; they can handle properly workflows with upper level layers&groups and nested elements in upper level groups. With more hierarchy they will work too, if active layer is not twice nested element (otherwise "down"-script will switch to uppermost layer and "up"-script will simply do nothing). But I really very rarely deal with more than once nested groups and at the worst one can do good old mouse click if too necessary (ore use legacy Alt+[/] shortcuts, they still work on all non-hidden layers howsoever nested).

Sorry, I'm not a programmer by far, so full-functional code is beyond my brains; furthermore, these scripts are quite bulky too, I suppose. But they work. (For example, I assign "up"-cycle to F3, "down"-cycle to F4 and "toggle-visibility"-script to F2; for me this combination is quite handy and saves much time).

"Cycle-down"-script

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;
//===========
var gropp = doc.layerSets.length;
var docl = doc.layers.length;
var sublayer = 0;
//alert(gropp)
for (i=0; i < gropp;)
{
sublayer = sublayer + doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
i++;
}
//==============
var a = -1
var kk = -1
var aa = -1
//если активный слой - элемент высшего порядка:
for(i=0; i<docl;)
{
  if(doc.layers[i]==currentLayer)
  {
     a=i;
     i = docl;
  }
  else{ i++;}
}
//если активный слой - элемент группы:
if (a<0)
{
  for (i=0; i<gropp;)
  {
     var subdocl = doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
     for (k=0; k<subdocl;)
     {
       if(doc.layerSets[i].layers[k]==currentLayer)
       {
          aa = i;
          kk = k;
          k = doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
          i = gropp-1;
       }
       else { k++; }
      }
     i++;
  }
}
//ACTIVATING
//если активный слой - слой высшего порядка:
if (kk<0)
{
    //если активный слой - группа (т.е. нижележ. слой - внутри её):
    for (i=0; i<gropp;)
    {
        if (doc.layerSets[i] == currentLayer)
        {
            var nLayer = doc.layerSets[i].layers[0];
            var check = nLayer.visible;
            doc.activeLayer = nLayer;
            var isGroup = true;
            var isActived = true;
            if (check == false)
            doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
            i = gropp;
        }
        else {i++;}
    }
    //если активный слой - простой слой (будет обрабатываться в try-catch):
    if (isGroup != true)
    {
        for (i=0; i<docl;)
        {
            if (doc.layers[i]==currentLayer)
            {
                numm = i;
                i=docl;
            }
            else {i++;}
        }
    }
}
else
//(если активный слой - подобъект (элемент группы), т.е. известны (неотриц.) aa и kk:
{
    //если элемент группы - последний в ней (будет обрабатываться в try-catch):
    if (kk == subdocl-1)
    {
        for (i=0; i<docl;)
        {
            if (doc.layers[i] == doc.layerSets[aa])
            {
                numm = i;
                i = docl;
            }
            else {i++;}
        }
    }
    //если не последний в группе, то проще:
    else
    {
        var nLayer = doc.layerSets[aa].layers[kk+1];
        var check = nLayer.visible;
        doc.activeLayer = nLayer;
        var isActived = true;
        if (check == false)
        doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
    }
}

//try-catch секция для последних вариантов (самых нижних слоёв):
try
{
    //alert ("isActived is " + isActived)
    if (isActived != true)
    {
        var nLayer = doc.layers[numm+1];
        var check = nLayer.visible;
        doc.activeLayer = nLayer;
        if (check == false)
        doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
    }
}
catch(e)
{
  var nLayer = doc.layers[0];
  var check = nLayer.visible;
  doc.activeLayer = nLayer;
  if (check == false)
  doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
}
```

"Cycle-up" script

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;

var gropp = doc.layerSets.length;
var docl = doc.layers.length;

var a = -1
var kk = -1
var aa = -1

//если активный слой - элемент высшего порядка:
for(i=0; i<docl;)
{
  if(doc.layers[i]==currentLayer)
  {
     a=i;
     i = docl;
  }
  else{ i++;}
}

//если активный слой - элемент группы:
if (a<0)
{
  for (i=0; i<gropp;)
  {
     var subdocl = doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
     for (k=0; k<subdocl;)
     {
       if(doc.layerSets[i].layers[k]==currentLayer)
       {
          aa = i;
          kk = k;
          k = doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
          //модернизируем скрипт: вносим сразу в этот цикл обработку активизации.
            //если элемент группы - первый в ней (активизируем саму группу - гипероним):
          if (kk==0)
          {
              var pLayer = doc.layerSets[i];
              var check = pLayer.visible;
              doc.activeLayer = pLayer;
              //var isGroup = true;
              var isActived = true;
              if (check == false)
              doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
          }
            //если не первый, то просто слой вверх:
          else
          {
              var pLayer = doc.layerSets[i].layers[kk-1];
              var check = pLayer.visible;
              doc.activeLayer = pLayer;
              var isActived = true;
              if (check == false)
              doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
          }
          i = gropp-1;
       }
       else { k++; }
     }
     i++;
  }
}
//если активный слой - высший элемент; нам известно (неотриц) a:
else
{
    if (a==0)
    a=docl;
    for (i=0; i<gropp;)
    {
        //если предыдущий слой - последний элемент находящейся выше группы:
        if (doc.layerSets[i] == doc.layers[a-1])
        {
            var subdocl = doc.layerSets[i].layers.length;
            var pLayer = doc.layerSets[i].layers[subdocl-1];
            var check = pLayer.visible;
            doc.activeLayer = pLayer;
            var isActived = true;
            if (check == false)
            doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
            i = gropp;
        }
        else {i++;}
    }
    if (isActived != true)
    {
        var pLayer = doc.layers[a-1];
        var check = pLayer.visible;
        doc.activeLayer = pLayer;
        if (check == false)
        doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
    }
}
```

"Bonus" - "toggle visibility"-script

```
var currentLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer;
currentLayer.visible = !currentLayer.visible
```

Note:
Save them as *.jsx files and put in C:\Program Files\Adobe\%Your Adobe Version Folder%\Presets\Scripts